# Android 1.6 Mapview doesn't show traffic until user interacts with the map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a MapActivity. If it's set to an appropriate location and zoom level to see traffic none is shown after it's first created until you interact with the map (click on it, drag, etc) at which point traffic shows up. Naturally I want traffic to show up without any user interaction after it loads but I've been unable to figure out how to trigger it. Any ideas?

From my MapActivity inherited class:

```
private MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.map);
 mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 mapView.setTraffic(true);
}
```

And here's whats in R.layout.map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="...MY API KEY HERE..."
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

postInvalidate() after a suitable delay should do as a workaround, what kind of delay times have you tried?

Comment: At your suggestion I gave this another try. I placed mapView.postInvalidateDelayed(5000); in OnStart() for this activity and watched it get hit in debug mode and then sat and waited for traffic to appear for a good 30 seconds. Didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Actually you are correct. postInvalidate after a delay does indeed work if it kicks off after the map is completely rendered. If it fires before first rendering is complete nothing happens.

A cheezy test fix I just did which works from onCreate since postInvalidateDelayed doesn't seem to do the trick (because I fired it from the ui thread perhaps?) anyway though ugly this works if the map renders in < 1000ms:

     Timer timer = new Timer();
     timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() { mapView.postInvalidate(); }
     }, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the `XML attrs` of the `MapView` but I couldn't find them.

My guess is that the map is not redrawn after using `setTraffic(true);`

Try calling `mapView.invalidate();`

Comment: Sadly I've already tried mapView.invalidate(); and mapView.postInvalidate() with a delay time but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug report on this, number [10317](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10317). From my research, when you turn on either traffic or streetview mode on a MapView, a thread starts up to retrieve the data from Google servers. If the data is not back by the time the MapView draws itself, then the appropriate lines do not get displayed. User interaction causes a redraw and by then the data is usually present. Calling invalidate doesn't work because the thread doesn't start until your code finishes executing (i.e., the code that set the mode on). The workaround is to post a future message to invalidate the MapView causing a redraw then when (hopefully) the data is present. The fix would be for the thread that does the data fetching to cause a redraw when the data's been retrieved.